# How to convert List<String> of Strings to BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, string, decode, bufferedimage

I want to convert a Base64 String array to a `BufferedImage`.
The approach I tried to accomplish:

```
static BufferedImage decodeToImage(List<String> imageStrings) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    ByteBuffer imageByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(500000000);
    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        for (String imageString : imageStrings) {
            imageByteBuffer.put(imageString.getBytes());
        }

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteBuffer.array());
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

I want to return a `BufferedImage` but it returns null.

Comment: What is wrong with the method you tried to accomplish the task?

Comment: i want to return BufferedImage but it gives me null

Comment: Why are you passing a list of strings?

Comment: Because String has limited number of characters

Comment: Are you intending to use that base64 decoder for something?

Comment: Yes :) i need to decode

Comment: @anduplats "Because String has limited number of characters" a string can store up to around 2^31 characters, same as an array.

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: When i try to save String it removes some part of data from it

Comment: @anduplats what is stopping you from using it?

Comment: it gives me null but it should be not nuil

Comment: I think what @AndyTurner tries to say by *"Are you intending to use that base64 decoder for something?"*, is that *you are not using the base64 decoder, thus not actually decoding anything*. This is also the main reason why your code doesn't work. ;-)

Comment: @haraldK yep, that.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this:

```
public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(List<String> imageStrings) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(String.join("", imageStrings));
        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this kind of defeats the purpose of using `List<String>` as the `join` will impose the same limitation on string lengths as simply using a single string as argument in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at what are you getting in?

Cause this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String base64String = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...=";
    String[] strings = base64String.split(",");
    List<String> param = new ArrayList<String>();
    param.add(strings[1]);
    BufferedImage bi = decodeToImage(param);
    System.out.println("BufferedImage: " + bi);
}

static BufferedImage decodeToImage(List<String> imageStrings) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    ByteBuffer imageByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(500000000);
    try {
        for (String imageString : imageStrings) {
          imageByteBuffer.put(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(imageString));
        }
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteBuffer.array());
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error?");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

Will print

BufferedImage: BufferedImage@7eda2dbb: type = 6 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 32 numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@6576fe71 transparency = 3 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 302 height = 232 #numDataElements 4 dataOff[0] = 3

But if I just give it the whole base64 text, with the image info in front

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String base64String = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...=";
    String[] strings = base64String.split(",");
    List<String> param = new ArrayList<String>();
    param.add(base64String); //THIS IS THE DIFFERENT LINE
    BufferedImage bi = decodeToImage(param);
    System.out.println("BufferedImage: " + bi);
    }
```

It will print null

Replace base64String with a valid base 64 encoded png from

http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image

I cut it down in this example cause otherwise it becomes several thousand characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Is the maximum length of a string in Java *really* a problem for your code? If not, I'd simplify your code like this (and fix the decoding bug):

```
static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {
    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();    
        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoder.decode(imageString)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Or, if you really have a problem with the length of the strings (Base64 does produce output longer than the input, so it *may* make sense in extreme cases, but verify this, as it otherwise complicates your code unnecessary), keep the list of strings. I'd simply skip the `ByteBuffer` and use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead, as it's much easier to work with.

```
static BufferedImage decodeToImage(List<String> imageStrings) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOuputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOuputStream();

        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        for (String imageString : imageStrings) {
            buffer.write(decoder.decode(imageString));
        }

        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

PS: While you should generally close streams, the `close()` method on `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` are no-ops.

Answer (score 0):

Buffers are little bit tricky to work with. Might be a good idea to take a look here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip()

As far as I can remember you have to prepare the buffer before you can read it; the position of the internal 'cursor' has to be set to the start position from where you then can read 'capacity' bytes.
Well, as I said: As far as I can remember. It's more then twelve years ago I had to directly work with buffers.